# Facebook auth using passport.js is not working

Tags: passport.js, facebook-authentication, passport-facebook

[image]

I am working with node.js in the backend. I am using a passport-facebook and cookie-session for authentication. But the error is showing every time (please check the added pic). I have rechecked my code various times, with no error or problems with the development side. Is it the problem of Facebook itself? Or I have to do any update on the developer.facebook.com console?

This the passport.js file
[image]

Comment: What is the callback URL you configured in passport?

Comment: I have edited the question with passport.js file code. Now you can check it.

Comment: Did you add your callback URL as a Valid OAuth Redirect URI in the Facebook developer app settings?

Comment: Errors and code should be added as text, not images, please.